# Escaping braces in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a situation where I take a file and I do proper Java escaping and replace all single quotes with two single quotes.

```
String fileContent = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(fileContent).replace("'","''");
```

Then an SQL statement is put together and passed on to do an `executeUpdate()` later on.

My problem is that the file ends up containing a curly opening brace without a closing one, and hibernate is not very happy about that. I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Unmatched braces for alias path
```

The failing statement looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (a_column) VALUES ('bla bla {more bla bla')
```

Using setParameter() is unfortunately not an option without rewriting everything.

Are there any ways I can bypass this hibernate feature or escape the characters?

Comment: Why do you need to escape Strings? Hibernate will do that for you. Just `setParameter` the raw String.

Comment: Can you show the SQL and relevant code in question?

Comment: @Thilo setParameter is unfortunately not an option since it involves rewriting a lot of code.

Comment: How much code can this be? You don't have to do it everywhere at once, just for the "problematic" queries (like the one you mention). But really, not using bind variables is almost a code defect (and isn't that the natural way to write queries when you use Hibernate -- especially when going through entities?).

Comment: FWIW, not being able to have braces in string literals is apparently either a Hibernate bug or a JPA limitation: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2744  https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/JPA-12

Comment: I never found a solution to my problem that worked. It looks like setParameter is the only way to go. It turns out I can solve my problem by converting the files I was trying to read because they were actually in the wrong format.